# Minimum area of Inscribed Square

Tags: geometry, area, gre-exam

GRE study guide asks

> The perimeter of square S is 40. Square T is inscribed in square S.
>   What is the least possible area of square T?

Choices are

1. 45
2. 48
3. 49
4. 50
5. 52

They say answer is 50. How do they even get this? T has lengths less than 10, so it can be 1 x 1 square, or 9 x 9 square. Please guide.

[image]

Comment: "Inscribed" means that all four vertices of $T$ lie on the boundary of $S$.

Comment: @rogerl Wouldn't that be one square on top of another. Would it look like this http://cdn-1.analyzemath.com/middle_school_math/grade_9/graphs/geometry_grade_9_11.gif Then how it least area = 50?

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility. The four vertices don't have to be evenly placed, in the middle of the sides, like in that diagram, but that is indeed the kind of picture that the question asks about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is inscribed it means that all vertices of $T$ lie on $S$. Like this

[image]

This divides the square into 4 triangle pieces and one square piece. We need to find the hypotenuse of the triangle piece to find the area of the inner square. The triangle has 2 sides of length 5. Using the pythagorean theorem yields  $h = \sqrt(5^2 + 5^2) = \sqrt{50}$. The area of a square with side length $h$ is $h^2$ so the area of the inner square is $\sqrt{50}^2 = 50$. Now you may wonder why the inscription has to be like this to yield a minimum. 
Lets consider the general case.

The area of the inner square is minimized when the area of the outer triangles is maximized. You can consider the vertices of the inner square dividing the sides of the outer square into two pieces. In the optimal case the length of these pieces are the same. This intuitively seems in the first diagram we can prove this to be true in general.

[image]

Let $L$ be the side length of the square. Say the vertices divides the side into pieces of length $a$ and $b$. We know that $a + b = L$ so $b = L - a$. Notice that all the triangles have the same area. So we only need to minimize one. The area of the triangle, $A$, will be $A = \frac{1}{2}ab = \frac{1}{2}a(L - a)$. We can find the minimum without calculus because this is a parabola. We just need to find the vertex of the parabola. Instead of completing the square, we can use the roots of the parabola as we have it in factored form. Recall that if the parabola has roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ then its vertex has an $x$ coordinate of $\frac{r_1 + r_2}{2}$(Note that we dont care about the actual value of the maximum area for this proof, but rather the value of $a$ that maximizes the area of the triangle). Since our quadratic has roots $0$ and $L$, then the x coordinate of the vertex is $\frac{0 + L}{2} = \frac{L}{2}$. Therefore the values of $a$ and $b$ that maximize the triangle area is $a = \frac{L}{2}$, $b = L - \frac{L}{2} = \frac{L}{2}$. This yields the result that the minimum case has $a = b$.

Comment: This is quite thorough and I'm still soaking in your explanation. What happens if you want to find maximum area of inscribed square? This means you'd have to minimize outside triangles. Will post follow-up question and link here.

Comment: @Rhonda Say we have a shape $S$, and another shape $D$ that is completely inscribed in it(no part of $D$ is outside of $S$). We know that $\text{Area}(D) \leq \text{Area}(S)$. From this we can see that the maximum possible area for $D$ is the area of $S$. So the maximum inscribed square would be the square itself. You can also think of this in terms of the minimization. We know the area of a triangle cannot be negative, which means its minimum can be 0. If $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ then the area of the triangle is 0. Think of what the diagram looks like if $a = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of an "inscribed" square in a square is that all of the smaller square's vertices lies on the boundaries of the larger square.

Notice that for this to happen, the smaller square's vertices will divide each side of the larger square into two segments, the same on each side. Let's call their lengths $a$ and $b.$ We have that $a + b = 10.$ The side length of the smaller square is, by Pythagoras, $s = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}.$ Then the area of the smaller square must be $s^{2} = a^{2} + b^{2}.$

You can use calculus here, but common sense also tells us that the minimum occurs when $a = b = \frac{10}{2} = 5.$ So the minimum area of the smaller square is $5^{2} + 5^{2} = \boxed{50}.$ This is answer choice $4.$

Answer (score 0):

Another explanation [Continuation of Jeevan Devaranjan ] A= (1/2) *a(L-a)=-(1/2)(a^2-aL)= -(1/2)(a^2-2*a*L/2+L^2/4)+L^2/8=-(1/2)*(a-L/2)^2+L^2/8; In order to maximize A; a-L/2=0 Hence a=(1/2)*L

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a live simulation (in Polish)
[here](http://oblicz.com.pl/kwadrat-wpisany-w-kwadrat/).
The orange point in the Geogebra applet (at the bottom of the page) is active. Change its position to see a result.