# Maximum area of inscribed square

Tags: geometry, area, gre-exam

This is follow-on from [Minimum area of Inscribed Square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623865/minimum-area-of-inscribed-square)

If I have square S with perimeter 40, i.e. each side 10, and I have inscribed square T, what is the Maximum area of T?

How do I even go about solving this?

[image]

Comment: $S$ is inscribed in itself, so $100$. If $T=S$ is unacceptable, we can get close, but there is no max.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Based on k-jiang answer, the maximum area would be _approaching_ 100

Comment: As the comment above says, if we consider $S$ to be a square inscribed in itself, the answer is exactly $100$. If we do not allow that, there is no max, though the *supremum* is $100$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a square is inscribed in this larger square, all of its vertices must lie on the vertices of the larger square. This problem is trivial - just make the squares the same size by placing the vertices of the inscribed square atop the vertices of the original square. The answer is $10^{2} = \boxed{100}.$